# Bash if blocking elif

Tags: bash, if-statement, scripting

I am trying to write a calculator script but the first `if` blocks the `elif`. What I mean is when I try to run it I press 1 but it runs as if I pressed 2. Here is my code.

```
echo "For Advanced mode press 1"
echo "For Help press 2"

loop=1
while [ $loop=1 ]; do

    read n

    if [ $n=2 ]; then
            echo "To use the calculator follow the promptings."
            echo "If asked, the operators are: "
            echo "* for multiplication, / for division."
            echo "+ for addition, - for subtraction."
            echo "% for modulus, which is division remainder"
            echo "== is equal to, != is not equal to."
            echo "** for exponents" 
            n=""

    elif [ $n=1 ]; then
            read a
            break
    fi

done
echo "_______________________"
echo "What would you like to do?"
echo "Press 1 for basic arith"
echo -n "Press 2 for geometry"
read choice
loop=2

if [ $choice=1]; then
    while [ $loop=2 ]; do
        echo -n "Enter X Value: "
        read x
    echo -n "Enter Operator: "
    read op
    echo -n "Enter Y Value: "
    read y
    ans=$((x $op y))
    echo "$x $op $y = $ans"
    echo "____________________"
    echo "To input a new function, press enter"
    read cont
    done
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

The `[` built-in is used for evaluating conditions. There must be a space after the opening `[` and a space before before the closing `]`, otherwise it's incorrect syntax.

Inside a `[ ... ]` expression, you can use various conditional operators. One such operator is `=`. You must put spaces before and after an operator, otherwise it's not recognized as an operator.

For example, `[ $n=2 ]` where the value of `n` is 1, will be evaluated as `[ 1=2 ]`. The `1=2` is not evaluated as a condition, because there are no spaces around it. The `1=2` will be evaluated as a string "1=2". And any non empty string in Bash is *truthy*, so the statement `[ 1=2 ]` yields true, even if it doesn't "look like" it would be true.

You must write `[ "$n" = 2 ]` so that `=` is interpreted as the conditional operator, and the expression doesn't become a single string. Note that spaces are extremely important in Bash. Spaces separate the logical elements of a program, without spaces expressions are concatenated as strings.

Also notice that I added double quotes around the variable. This is to protect the expression in case the variable is empty. If for example you write `[ $n = 2 ]` and the variable is empty, then the expression will be evaluated as `[  = 2 ]`, which is a malformed expression, and the script will crash with an error.

Comment: Nice answer. the `[` counts the number of arguments it's given, and does different things based on that number. Also note that bash's builtin `[[` is more sensible about unquoted variables (they get replaced by an empty string, so they don't "lose their place" as an argument).

Answer (score 0):

Put spaces between your condition elements like `$n = 2` not `$n=2`.You should pass it's arguments as whitespace separated words. So your code should be as following:

```
echo "For Advanced mode press 1"
echo "For Help press 2"

loop=1
while [ $loop = 1 ]; do

    read n

    if [ $n = 2 ]; then
        echo "To use the calculator follow the promptings."
        echo "If asked, the operators are: "
        echo "* for multiplication, / for division."
        echo "+ for addition, - for subtraction."
        echo "% for modulus, which is division remainder"
        echo "== is equal to, != is not equal to."
        echo "** for exponents" 
        n=""

    elif [ $n = 1 ]; then
        read a
        break
    fi

done
echo "_______________________"
echo "What would you like to do?"
echo "Press 1 for basic arith"
echo -n "Press 2 for geometry"
read choice
loop=2

if [ $choice = 1 ]; then
    while [ $loop = 2 ]; do
        echo -n "Enter X Value: "
        read x
    echo -n "Enter Operator: "
    read op
    echo -n "Enter Y Value: "
    read y
    ans=$((x $op y))
    echo "$x $op $y = $ans"
    echo "____________________"
    echo "To input a new function, press enter"
    read cont
    done
fi
```